# linear transformations/effect of translating all vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a$ be a ﬁxed vector. The function $T_a$ deﬁned by $T_a(v) = a + v$ has the eﬀect of translating all vectors by adding $a$. Show this is not a linear transformation. Explain why it is not possible to realize $T_a$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by multiplying by a $3\times 3$ matrix.

The answer is: Linear transformations take $0$ to $0$. Also $T_a (u + v) \neq T_a(u) + T_a(v)$.

I don't understand how the book got to this conclusion, can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear maps satisfy two properties:

1. $T(u+v)=T(u)+T(v)$ and
2. $T(av)=aT(v)$

A quick corollary of number 2 tells you that if $T$ is linear, then $T(0)=T(0*v)=0*T(v)$ by the property that multiplying by zero gives you zero.

As you noted, $T_a(0)=a\ne 0$, so it is not linear. You can also see this by the first property:

$T_a(u+v)=u+v+a\ne T_a(u)+T_a(v)=u+v+2a$.

edit: This map also could be linear...when $a=\vec{0}$, which I assume they eliminated as a possibility.